# Change specific value of form before sending

Tags: angular, forms

I have a User registration page, where I want the user to be able to upload his own avatar picture. 
My logic so far, is to upload picture, call on change a function that transforms the picture into a UInt8Array to store it on Mongo. 
So, I have:

```
 onRegister(form):void{
this.authService.register(form.value).subscribe(res =>{
  this.router.navigateByUrl('/auth');
})}
```

This function is called on submit, which takes the whole form data and sends it to authService.register.
However, the UInt8Array data is stored in another variable. How can I "open" form.value to modify the avatar value?

html for reference:

```
<form #frmRegister="ngForm" class="login-container" (ngSubmit)="onRegister(frmRegister)">
      <p><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Nombre" ngModel required></p>
      <p><input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" ngModel required></p>
      <p><input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Contraseña" ngModel required></p>
      <p><label name="signature_UintArray">Avatar</label>
        <input type="file" name="avatar" placeholder="avatar"(change)="avatartoUintArray($event)"></p>  
      <p>
        <label for="role">Elige un rol</label>
          <select [(ngModel)]="selectedRol" name="role" placeholder="avatar" ngModel >
            <option *ngFor="let rol of role" [ngValue]="rol">{{rol}}</option>
          </select>
          </p>
      <p><input type="submit" value="Register"></p>
    </form>
```

And avatartoUintArray()

```
avatartoUintArray(archivo){
    (archivo, callback) =>{
      let fr = new FileReader();
      fr.onload = function(){
        var arrayBuffer = this.result;
        var array = new Uint8Array(<ArrayBuffer>arrayBuffer);
        callback(array);
        };
   fr.readAsArrayBuffer(archivo.target.files[0]);
  }
    }

  callback(Uint8info){
    this.avatar = Uint8info;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
onRegister(form) :void {
  const formValue = { ...form.value };
  const formValueForApi = {
    ...formValue,
    avatar: // I assume the key is called avatar, overwrite it to what you would like.
  };
  console.log(formValueForApi); See if it is what you would like
  this.authService.register(formValueForApi).subscribe(res =>{
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/auth'); 
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Angular form patchValue method which you can use this patching the form value.

```
this.form.get('fieldname').patchValue(fieldvalue);
```

Comment: This is fine when the form is declared in typescript, but actually my form only exists in the html, as "<form #frmRegister="ngForm" class="login-container" (ngSubmit)="onRegister(frmRegister)">". I don't know how to get this form data to modify it with patchvalue.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with the use of View Child:
 Declared inside the class:

```
@ViewChild('frmRegister',{static:true}) registerform: NgForm;
```

and then:

```
this.registerform.value.avatar = value;
```

It works like a charm.